# Using sed to write a script to copy a number of lines from one file to another

Tags: bash, formatting, sed

I'm trying to write a script that takes two files and a number as its parameters and copies that number of lines from one file to the other. Here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

file1=$1
file2=$2
lines=$3

sed -n '1,\'$lines\'p' $file1 > $file2
```

Obviously the problem is the formatting of the `$lines` parameter. What's the right way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: head -n $lines $file1 > $file2

Comment: Hehe. Done. I made it a comment since it didn't directly answer your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed -n -e "1,${lines}p" $file1 > $file2

alternately:

head -n $lines $file1 > $file2

Comment: variables containing filenames must be double-quoted

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to escape the single quotes. Do something like this -

```
#!/bin/bash

file1=$1
file2=$2
lines=$3

sed -n '1,'$lines'p' $file1 > $file2
```

**OR**

```
sed -n "1,"$lines"p" $file1 > $file2
```

Comment: variables containing filenames must be double-quoted